# Given Post doc interview at IIT Bombay 4 months back but have yet not received any letter. What to do apart from talking to supervisor?

Tags: postdocs

I have given interview for postdoc at IIT Bombay 4 months back and have still not got any formal letter. However, I asked and got news from multiple sources that I have been recommended for the position (and the sources are very legit). But then why have I not got any offer up till now.? General time they take is 2-4 weeks. Should I talk to Assistant Registrar who is responsible for sending offer letters?

Comment: Definitely call them (not necessarily the person sending the offer letters, that would be a bit presomptuous, but try the potential future PI) - it cannot hurt!

Answer (score 1):

You should ask someone responsible for this position, maybe a faculty member in the interview or maybe the administration on whether there are any updates they can share with you concerning the position.

Four months seems like a long time unless the start date is still far in the future. You can certainly ask for an update, though asking if you have been chosen might be too bold. You will probably learn *something*.

Comment: I have asked the faculty. He says it is with the Institute committee. I have asked him several times